# previous key to current key

Tags: python

I am new with the concept of dictionaries and trying to learn them. What I have is a dictionary like this:

```
{'cars': [{'values': [1, 534],
  {'values': [25,32,164]
 'bikes': [{'values': [23,12,1]
  {'values': [2,4]
  {'values': [68,69]
  {'values': [4,93]
```

What I try to achieve is add Ids to all inner values starting from 1

Comment: The index of the first item in a list is always 0 in Python, you can't change that.

Comment: what value do you want to have at `try_dict['cars'][0]`?

Comment: Unless you want to add some kind of value at [0] I don't see any point starting at [1] when the default is like that.

Comment: I don't want so see any result from try_dict['cars'][0]. What I am trying to do is like add IDs for my inner values.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I want to give Ids to each value groups of cars and bikes

Comment: You can either have the IDs start from 0, or use a dict instead of a list: `{"cars": {1: {...}, 2: {...}}}`

Comment: Could you please accept the answer that you found most useful by ticking it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the ID as part of the value group, like this:

```
{'cars': [{'values': [1, 534], 'sedan': 1, 'count': 2, 'ID': 1},
  {'values': [25, 32, 164], 'sedan': 1, 'count': 10, 'ID': 2}],
 'bikes': [{'values': [23, 12, 1], 'road': 0, 'count': 9},
 ...
```

You can do:

```
for i in range(len(try_dict['cars'])):
    try_dict['cars'][i]['ID'] = i+1
```

If you want what Phydeaux suggests, you can do:

```
new_dict = {'cars': {}}
for i in range(len(try_dict['cars'])):
    new_dict['cars'][i+1] = try_dict['cars'][i]
```

Which will give you:

```
{'cars': {1: {'values': [1, 534], 'sedan': 1, 'count': 2},
  2: {'values': [25, 32, 164], 'sedan': 1, 'count': 10}}}
```

If you want not just `cars` but also `bikes` (and maybe trucks, trains, whatever...). Use:

```
new_dict = {}
for key in try_dict.keys():
    new_dict[key] = {}
    for i in range(len(try_dict[key])):
        new_dict[key][i+1] = try_dict[key][i]
```

This will give you:

```
{'cars': {1: {'values': [1, 534], 'sedan': 1, 'count': 2},
  2: {'values': [25, 32, 164], 'sedan': 1, 'count': 10}},
 'bikes': {1: {'values': [23, 12, 1], 'road': 0, 'count': 9},
  2: {'values': [2, 4], 'road': 1, 'count': 24},
  3: {'values': [68, 69], 'sedan': 0, 'count': 28},
  4: {'values': [4, 93], 'sedan': 0, 'count': 6}}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using a simple function:

```
def idx(dict, key):
    dict = dict
    dict[key].insert(0, 0)
    return dict
```

Full Code:

```
def idx(dict, key):
    dict = dict
    dict[key].insert(0, 0)
    return dict

dict = {'cars': [{'values': [1, 534],
   'sedan': 1,
   'count': 2},
  {'values': [25,32,164],
   'sedan': 1,
   'count': 10}],
 'bikes': [{'values': [23,12,1],
   'road': 0,
   'count': 9},
  {'values': [2,4],
   'road': 1,
   'count': 24},
  {'values': [68,69],
   'sedan': 0,
   'count': 28},
  {'values': [4,93],
   'sedan': 0,
   'count': 6}]}

dict = idx(dict, "cars")
print(dict["cars"][1])
```

Explanation:
Replace dictionary with a new edited dictionary:

```
dict = {key: [...,...,...]}
dict = idx(dict, key)
```

Function is using the `.insert` method to insert 0 for the value of the first index to the key provided.

Learn more about Python `.insert()` method at:
[

> https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_insert.asp